# Convert array into string if array is within an array using javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a scenario wherein I need to get all [microtime] in the array result which is processed using an ajax.

Here's the process

1. On dropdown change, I take the value and apply it in MySQL query.
2. It will return an array.

I was able to print_r the result.

But I want to get all [microtime] and all [sum(srp)]

[image]

Is there a possible way to do that.

Like, I want the result to be like this:
**microtime is converted to months <----this I already did

```
var months = [January,February,March..blablabla]
var sum    = [396484,629103,blablablabla]
```

Comment: Use foreach and divide your array into 2 different array months and sum. :)

Comment: Not clear to me what you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is complete solution

```
<?php
$data=
Array(
"0"=>array(
"microtime"=>1469700000.7834700,
"SUM(src)"=>396484
),
"1"=>array(
"microtime"=>1472000004.64866100,
"SUM(src)"=>629103
),
"2"=>array(
"microtime"=>1469700000.7834700,
"SUM(src)"=>396484
)
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre><br/><br/>";
$month=array();
$sum=array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
$month[]=date("M",$val["microtime"]);
$sum[]=$val["SUM(src)"];
}
?>
<script>
var months = '<?php echo json_encode($month);?>';
var sum = '<?php echo json_encode($sum); ?>'
</script>
```

and the output is

[image: output]

Thanks

Comment: How do I do if I want to pass that var months into a js file. Instead of having both js and php code in one file I have a separate js file.

Comment: `$data = $content;

    $month=array();
    $sum=array();
    foreach($content as $key=>$val){
    $month[]=date("M",$val["microtime"]);
    $sum[]=$val["SRP"];
    }
    $a = json_encode($month);
    $b = json_encode($sum);
    echo $a;
    echo $b;`

This is what I did. now in my js file(ajax)
`success: function (dataofconfirm) {
        alert(dataofconfirm);
        /*var data_id = dataofconfirm['microtime']; // "4831"
        alert(data_id);*/
      }`

How will di splice the 2 parts ([1,2,3,4][6,7,8,9])

Comment: I we define any js variable above the function then then we can directly use these var in any separate js file

Answer (score 3):

Use a foreach loop on your results and store the separate pieces in separate arrays.

```
$months = $sums = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $months[] = getMonthFromMicrotime($result['microtime']); // Using your custom function here
    $sums[] = $result['SUM(srp)'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play it with JavaScript than this can help you. Code is updated now and its working fine.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('microtime' => "1111111",'SUM(srp)' => "1"),
    array('microtime' => "2222222",'SUM(srp)' => "2")
);
$array = json_encode($array);
?>
<script>
var json = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).split('SUM(srp)').join('sum_srp'));
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
var microtime = [];
var sum = [];

window.onload = function() {
    for (var key in arr) {
        if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            microtime.push(arr[key].microtime);
            sum.push(arr[key].sum_srp);
        }
    }
    console.log(microtime);
    console.log(sum);
};

</script>
```